# custom permalink issue on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a plugin and accessed plugin page using this code:

```
add_filter('page_template', 'in_page_template4' );
  function in_page_template4(){
  global $wpdb;
  $new_page_title = 'Inventory';
  $new_page_title1 = 'inventory-details';
   $new_page_title2 = 'spanos-inventory';
    $new_page_title3 = 'trade-in-inventory';
    $ppid=$_GET['page_id'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts where ID='".$ppid."';";
 // $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts where post_name='".$new_page_title."';";
  $cnt_post = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

  if(count($cnt_post)!=0){ $page_title=$cnt_post[0]->post_name;
      if($new_page_title==$page_title){

        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/car_inventory.php';
        return $page_template;
      }elseif($new_page_title1==$page_title){
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inventory_details.php';
        return $page_template;
      }
      elseif($new_page_title2==$page_title){
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/car_inventory.php';
        return $page_template;
      }
        elseif($new_page_title3==$page_title){
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/car_inventory.php';
        return $page_template;
      }

  }
}
```

If we are using default permalink Plugin working nicely but when we used custom permalink plugin page showing **page not found error**.

Comment: What does the _custom_ permalink format actually look like? It's probably just not the same as the _default_ style you've hard-coded in your various `$page_template` assignment statements, hence you're never returning a valid `$page_template` under your current permalink style.

Answer (score 0):

In attempts to answer your question I would say you would want to change this section

```
dirname( __FILE__ )
```

to the actual directory you want like if you want the plugin dir

```
plugin_url('car_inventory.php');
```